# Pattern recognition for static images in Android (eg cards, vouchers etc.)

Tags: android, image-processing

I want to implement pattern recognition mechanism in Android. The use case is: You take the camera and scan "our specific company member card". This card has some individual patterns on it, like a red stripe. Another use case is scanning a specific voucher that has some visual fixed patterns as well.
I want the camera to detect that card or voucher by the visual patterns. No OCR.

Is there a suitable framework for Android you can recommend? Since that cards are not known by Google and for privacy reasons we don't want to use Cloud service providers. All I found are SDKs that use Cloud services or do not match the pattern recognition of my individual images.

Comment: If you are ok with using barcodes/QR codes take a look a zxing. However, this question is off-topic and will likely get closed on you.

Comment: No, the use case is explicitely to do pattern recognition. So its not about finding a solution like QR codes. In this case its really about frameworks, libraries and ways of pattern recognition in Android.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried  [OPENCV Processing and Java Library](http://ubaa.net/shared/processing/opencv/)?
It is open source and supports:

- real-time capture
- video file import
- basic image treatment
  (brightness, contrast, threshold, …)
- object detection (face, body, …)
- blob detection